# nginx rate limiting with X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I'm looking into rate-limiting using nginx's [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule).  However, requests are all coming from the same IP (a loadbalancer), with the real IP address in the headers.

Is there a way to have nginx rate-limit based on the ip in the `X-Forwarded-For` header instead of the ip of the source?

Comment: **Do not trust HTTP headers. It’s not something you can’t set to anything you want.**

Comment: HTTP headers can and should be trusted exactly because you can (and should) set it to anything you want (on the web server for the upstream).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, typical rate-limiting configuration definition string looks like:

```
 limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr zone=zone:16m rate=1r/s;
```

where `$binary_remote_addr` is the unique key for limiter. You should try changing it to `$http_x_forwarded_for` variable which gets the value of `X-Forwarded-For` header. Although this will increase memory consumption because `$binary_remote_addr` is using compressed binary format for storing IP addresses and `$http_x_forwarded_for` is not.

```
 limit_req_zone  $http_x_forwarded_for zone=zone:16m rate=1r/s;
```

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion, and in a quick test it works fine.  Thanks for pointing out the increased memory usage.

Comment: Beware there may be serious security concerns to this: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html

Comment: Note that the information in that blog post regarding symfony was addresses with the following: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html

Comment: If you use realip module, `$binary_remote_addr` variable gets set correctly.

Comment: What is 16m in this context?

Comment: @Esqarrouth The size of shared memory, namely “_zone_,” for that. 16 MiB.

Comment: **Do not trust HTTP headers. It’s not something you can’t set to anything you want.**

Comment: @КонстантинВан you can trust request headers if you know for sure they are always set or cleaned by a trusted reverse proxy/load balancer. Reject all non-proxied connections with a firewall or non-public network, or use a whitelist (on the original `$remote_addr`) for header usage like the RealIP module does.

Answer (score 6):

The `limit_req_zone` directive defines the variable to be used as key for request grouping.
Usually, the `$binary_remote_addr` is used rather than `$remote_addr` because it is smaller and saves space.

Maybe you alternatively want to use the [ngx_http_realip_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html).
This will rewrite the remote address variables to the address provided in a custom header and will also make logging and other variable usage easier.

Comment: +1 for RealIP module. When using this module, `$binary_remote_addr` and `$remote_addr` are set to the value of your configured header, typically `X-Forwarded-For` - so your standard variables are now the "real client IP address".
Run `nginx -V` to see if NGINX was built with `--with-http_realip`. Then config is as simple as:  
`set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;`
`real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;`
 , where the CIDR range is that of your upstream load balancer which is setting the `X-Forwarder-For` header.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example and demonstration of setting up real_ip using the header.

- We precise a header to take the ip from
- The client ip will be then overridden with that value
- Then we can keep using `$binary_remote_addr`

  - not always `x-forwarded-for` is used.
- That method can help too with logs (default format will work as `$remote_addr` now it's set to the overridden value)
- Nginx Module to use: [ngx_http_realip_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)
  Example of setting that up with Cloudflare (more than one server source, or ip range)

```
# Ipv4
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;

# Ipv6
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;

real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

- you can have that in a file. ex: `cloudflare_ip.conf` and add it to `conf.d`

You can see the usage of

- `set_real_ip_from`

  - only the requests coming from those ip's, the overriding will be applied to
- `real_ip_header`
- The header containing the client ip connecting through Cloudflare is `CF-Connecting-IP`
- Cloudflare [guide](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/restoring-visitor-ips/restoring-original-visitor-ips/)

And for the rate limit

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit_ip_10rs:10m rate=10r/s;
```

- We keep using `$binary_remote_addr`